# Data Fusion replication pipeline is not syncing data in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-data-fusion

Hi we want to replicate the data from Mysql(source) to GoogleBigquery(destination) we adopted the method described by google Docs with Data fusion replication pipeline as mentioned in Link
https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery

Berief of what we are doing:
Enabling bin log in MY SQL for CDC(Change data Capture)
creating a replication pipeline in data fusion
starting the pipeline and syncing the data

1. we are successfully able to create MySql data in comupute engine and enabling bin-log for CDC and provided all necessary permission to user for the data replication pipeline in my SQL
2. we are successful in  creating a data Fusion instance and able to create a replication pipeline
3. replication pipeline is able to fetch our SQL database details and target Big query is also set
4. On starting the pipeline it is tracking the Changes successfully (Insert,update and delete ) and table Schema is also created in Bigquery Successfully automatically.
5. **But we are getting PROBLEM that no data is getting transsferred to Bigquery table. In log what i have seen is loading batch of 1 event in to statging Bucket**

sharing the screenshot also
[image]

able to fetch every change from MYSQL but data is not transferring to bigquery
table schema was created but data is not transferred
**loading batch of 1 event in to statging Bucket**  **we are using developer mode and waited for more than 90 mins**

Comment: Shubham: Just to verify did you happen to follow the steps mentioned in this doc - https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery. Specifically around the driver installation

Comment: Could you also share logs for the Delta Assessor service from System Admin page? Data Fusion Home -> System Admin -> View Logs (Delta Accessor in services table).

Comment: Can you also provide the logs for the replication pipeline where the data write doesn't seem to be happening. The logs button is present in the screenshot you posted

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be happening because there may be a schema/data type mismatch with the BigQuery table and the source MYSQL database table on the columns.

For example: if you have a column in source table, in BigQuery this column is of `INT64` datatype with a length of 19, while in the source database table, it is `Integer` type with a length of 10, so you need to update the length of columns as per your datasize.